# Is Linux kernel 5.7 available on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: kernel

i'm using ubuntu 16.04

i know ubuntu 16.04 use linux kernel 4.4.x

but now i need to use linux kernel 5.7.x

so i will update linux kernel version 4.4.x to 5.7.1 in ubuntu 16.04

I am wondering if this update is ok.

if it has a problem, I would like to know what Linux kernel versions are available for Ubuntu 16.04.

Also, I would like to know what Linux kernels are available for each Ubuntu version.(16.04, 18.04, 20.04)

thank you!

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 provides two supported kermels, the GA kernel is 4.4, and the HWE kernel is 4.15 (ie moved to 16.10, 17.04, 17.10 before finally settling on 18.04 or the next LTS GA kernal).  5.7 is a test kernel only in Ubuntu (not even *groovy* uses it).

Comment: Kernel 5.7, if you can find a Ubuntu version, would default to using LZ4 compression, which is not available on Ubuntu 16.04. So you would probably need to compile it yourself, changing the kernel configuration to use GZIP. Then it should work fine, but do not expect any support for it.

Comment: Although it was a low quality question, thank you for your sincere answer. Thanks to you guys, i learned a lot

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu 16.04 provides two supported kernels,

- the GA (general availability) kernel is 4.4, and
- the HWE (hardware enablement) kernel is 4.15 (ie it progressed using the 16.10 kernel, 17.04, 17.10 before finally settling on 18.04 or the next LTS GA kernal).

For details on HWE (hardware enablement) see

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack
- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/RollingLTSEnablementStack

The two kernel options are Ubuntu 18.04 LTS are

- GA kernel is 4.15, and
- currently HWE is using 5.3 or 19.10's kernel, but will move to the 20.04 kernel soon (with 18.04.5).

Ubuntu 20.04 LTS is using the 5.4 kernel (HWE & GA are identical at this stage).

The 5.7 kernel is a *test* kernel only in Ubuntu (not even *groovy* uses it).

Comment: I thought it was at my usual standard :)      I don't see it as a valuable question, I doubt anyone beyond OP will be interested.. and facts were/are there.   Improved a little I suspect..

Comment: I went to answer (over comments) for the space primarily... and then looked for a duplicate, but couldn't find one...  I like wiki links (kernel choices), the rest doesn't matter